# Attaching PHP,jQuery login form to WP database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to add this [login form](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/schemeable-sliding-panel/) to my Wordpress.

It's stated that I need to create a MySQL database, but there is no explanation on how to insert the already existing WP database.

If I add the WP table in `table.sql`, will it work? or there is more customization I need to know of?

> There are some Wordpress plugins in the website that rely on the
>      user tables of Wordpress, thats why the need to incorporate with WP
>      table and not a standalone.

I am posting this here because comments are closed for questions in that page.

EDIT:

Folowing j0k advice i kept searching, and someone made the exact plugin for wordpress.

So to the ones that encounter this question and need a solution:

[Schemeable Sliding Panel](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/schemeable-sliding-panel/)

Comment: I think you may have some issues using that script with WordPress.  It uses PHP sessions, which WordPress clobbers - see [here](http://www.thinkingoutloud.co.za/content/20091012/php_wordpress_and_session) for example.  You might be better off finding a plugin that does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just need to insert `table.sql` inside your database. It will create only one table called `tz_members`.

That's all.

Comment: so, leave it as is. and just inject that file to my main wp database? Wordpress will see it as WP users? or @Sumit Malik suggestion is more compatible..?!

Comment: No, it will create a separate table for users, but not Wordpress user. This script seems to just create a member-only page where people can register/login and that's all. You will need more stuff if you want to provide a member page, profile, etc ... What do you really? A fancy login box or a new members layer ?

Comment: I would say a fancy login box, indeed :) i need Wordpress users, not new users that are not related to the database, other plugins wont recognize users as WP, and thats a problem. so i just keep looking i guess..

Comment: So this is not the script you want. And by the way, this script isn't related **AT ALL** to Wordpress. So I recommend you to find an other one. OR just take a look at the html/css used for the login box and apply this to your wordpress theme. But only apply html/css, not php!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a table then you don't need to create a table but alter it.

Instead of CREATE TABLE query in table.sql use ALTER TABLE query.

For already available database, fill up the related details in **connect.php**

Answer (score 1):

if you want it to be in your wordpress , dont make this `sql.table` instead use your own table
 that word press reconize for other components and modules.  your new table **will not be reconized by your whole website**
and in the file
`demo.php` just change this

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT id,usr FROM tz_members WHERE usr='{$_POST['username']}' AND pass='".md5($_POST['password'])."'"));
```

to your table and columns .

and in your login.php file , copy the demo.php to it or rename your file to demo.php and put those files in your login folder and customize the paths ,

this table `tz_members` is called only there where i told you.
good luck

Comment: Thanks, ill try that before moving on to WP plugins and report back if works

Comment: u dont need the `table.sql` , use yours . but u have accepted the first answer , so your problem is solved . good luck